# Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Michael Hartl) Chapter 2 Exercise 2.3.3.1 "Edit the user show page to display the content of the user’s first micropost."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Full descriptions of task sounds:
Edit the user show page to display the content of the user’s first micropost. (Use your technical sophistication (Box 1.1) to guess the syntax based on the other content in the file.) Confirm by visiting /users/1 that it worked.

My first idea was to update app/views/users/show.html.erb into

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Content:</strong>
  <%= @micropost.content %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

But seems I haven't got idea behind task? Any suggestions from what I should start from? 
Biggest thanks for your responses)

Comment: ...did you set `@micropost` in the controller?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be getting an `Undefined method 'content' for nil:NilClass` error. The problem is that `@micropost` is not defined in the controller method (action) and so is `nil`.

And you can't call the `content` method on a `nil` object since it doesn't respond to it. In other words, there is no instance method named `content` defined on `NilClass`.

To fix the error, define an instance variable `@micropost` in the `show` action of `UsersController`.

```
# users_controller.rb

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @micropost = @user.microposts.first
end
```

`@user.microposts.first` returns user's first post.

If the user has no posts associated with them, `@user.microposts.first` will return `nil`. So, you have to check if `@micropost` is `nil` before displaying it in the view.

```
# users/show.html.erb

<% if @micropost %> 
  <p>
    <strong>Content:</strong>
    <%= @micropost.content %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Many thanks for response. I have updated users_controller.rb with additional lines. Also in app/views/users/show.html.erb into I added
<p>
<strong>Micropost:</strong>
<%= @micropost %>

</p>

Comment: //FINAL COMMENT HERE:

Many thanks for response. I have updated users_controller.rb with additional lines. Also in app/views/users/show.html.erb into I added

`<p>
<strong>Micropost:</strong>
<%= @ micropost %>
</p>`

also tried,

`<p>
<strong>Micropost:</strong>
<%= @ user.microposts.first %>
</p>`

After all, in show page I am getting sort of id code like: 
**Micropost: #<Micropost:0x007f5560945860>**

Any clues what could be wrong there?

Comment: @RomasRan  `@user.microposts.first` gives the first `micropost` object. And if you try to display the object itself, you will get the internal representation of the object which is the classname followed by the memory location. You have to access its fields by calling the different methods available on the object. For example, if your post had a `content` field, you can call `@micropost.content` in your view. Make sure that `@micropost` exists in the controller as `@micropost = @user.microposts.first`. Makes sene?

Comment: @RomasRan, Updated my answer. See if it helps

Comment: It worked! Many thank for help @ArunKumar . Furthermore, there should be a condition made for action if there no micropost addressed for user otherwise error (undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass) pops out . Any practical advise?

Comment: @RomasRan, if the user doesn't have any microposts associated with him, `@user.microposts.first` will return `nil`. So, check in the view if `@micropost` is `nil`. If its not, go ahead and display the content. Wait, I'll update answer.

Comment: Working well! A lot of great help) Much obliged @ArunKumar

Answer (score 6):

I think you might be able to just do this in the users/show.html.erb:

```
@user.microposts.first.content
```

While not elegant, it's the simplest and satisfies the "edit the user show page" requirement of the exercise.

Comment: It would work `@user.microposts.first.content` for the sake of the exercise and just to display to content of the first post. However if you create a new user without any microposts or click on the 'show' link of a user without any microposts, you will get a NoMethodError.

Answer (score 2):

I also added @user.id because without it you don't know which user to add the microposts to for testing.  Then you need to test to see if there is a microposts in order not break the code trying to display nil.

```
<p>
  <strong>ID:</strong>
  <%= @user.id %>
</p>


<% if @user.microposts.first %>
<p>
  <strong>First Post:</strong>
  <%= @user.microposts.first.content %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to user_controller.rb in #def show

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@micropost_first = @user.microposts.first.content
```

Then added to show.html.erb

```
<%= @micropost_first %>
```